# A weird exercise for proving a tensor

Tags: tensors

I have the following exercise:

Give a variant arbitrary values in some coordinate system and let
it transform by the proper tensor rules. Show that this construction produces a
tensor. More specifically, single out a particular coordinate system $Z^{i'}$ and choose an arbitrary collection of values $T^{i'j'}_{k'}$. Then, in coordinates $Z^i$ , define $T^{ij}_k$ by

$T^{ij}_k=T^{i'j'}_{k'}J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}J^{k'}_{k'}$

Show that $T^{ij}_k$ is a tensor. Here the $J$:s represent entries in the jabocian matrix. If $T$ is a tensor the definition here is

$T^{ij}_k=T^{i'j'}_{k'}J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}J^{k}_{k'}$

I have several questions.

What does it mean to "single out" a coordinate system?

The exercise also wants me to choose a collection of values for the symbol $T^{ij}_k$. That would mean I'd have to make up 27 different values for it, right? I fail to see why this would get me anywhere.

The only step I see here is to replace $J^{k'}_{k'}=1$ so I get $T^{ij}_k=T^{i'j'}_{k'}J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}$, which doesn't seem to help either.

What do I need to do here, exactly?

Comment: Is this the pavel grinfield book ? :-)

Comment: Indeed it is lol.

Comment: If I recall, he defined a tensor as a variant that transforms through some set of rules. I think the idea here is that he defined the tensor in the context of some coordinate system (primed), then he used this definition to write out the definition in an arbitrary one (unprimed). So, to prove that our $T_{k}^{ij}$ is a tensor, find a new coordinate system and show that it transforms by the jacobians again.

Comment: ^ take the above with a grain of salt as I am not fully confident in the subject yet

Comment: Yes the definition of the above tensor T according to the book would be $T^{ij}_{k}=T^{i'j'}_{k'}J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}J^k_{k'}$. However, I don't really know how to really get there and I also have the other things I asked about that bother me about that assignment

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to chose a third coordinate system (say $Z^{i''}$) and then show that changing coordinates from $Z^{i}$ to $Z^{i''}$ gives the same result as the components of $T$ in the system $Z^{i''}$. Does that make sense?

Edit:
You noted that $Z^i=Z(Z'(Z''))$, so the chain rule tells you that
$$\delta^i_j = J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{i''}J^{i''}_j$$
Hence
$$J^i_{i''} = J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{i''}.$$
Can you go on?

Remember that I asked you to show that
$$T^{ij}_k J^{i''}_iJ^{j''}_jJ^k_{k''} = T^{i''j''}_{k''}.$$

Comment: So you want me to express  $T^{ij}_k$ in double primed coordinates right? But how do I express $Z^i$ in terms of $Z^i''$ other than $Z^i=Z(Z'(Z''))$?

Comment: @Joel You got the idea. That is all you have. I added an edit. Is it clearer now?